# Редактирование шаблона WP доп блок "редактирование страницы"

Tags: wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin, wp-theme

Когда редактируешь страницу в Wordpress  справа есть сайдбар с "опубликовать","атрибуты страницы", "миниатюра записи" и многие другие...
Как добавить свой функционал блок в этот сайдбар?(или до контента страницы, или после)
Необходимо написать плагин?но с редактированием какого шаблона?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно это делается с помощью плагина ACF. (www.advancedcustomfields.com) Через него можно создавать новые поля и указывать где их нужно выводить.